# Log all messages to non-root logger in python

Tags: python, logging

The docs for [`logging.Logger.setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) state the following:

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the root logger is created with level WARNING.
>
> The term ‘delegation to the parent’ means that if a logger has a level of NOTSET, its chain of ancestor loggers is traversed until either an ancestor with a level other than NOTSET is found, or the root is reached.
>
> If an ancestor is found with a level other than NOTSET, then that ancestor’s level is treated as the effective level of the logger where the ancestor search began, and is used to determine how a logging event is handled.
>
> If the root is reached, and it has a level of NOTSET, then all messages will be processed. Otherwise, the root’s level will be used as the effective level.

I ran into this issue recently trying to set a non-root logger's level to `NOTSET`, so that it would log everything I threw at it. Instead, it just cut off less severe messages to the default setting of the root logger.

How do I make a non-root logger log all messages of any severity *without* delegating to a parent at any point?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. The description of your issue just seems to confirm the documentation. And to log all messages for a non-root logger, can't you just simply set that logger's level to DEBUG (while leaving root at, e.g., WARN)?

Comment: @9769953. The problem is that I have custom levels made with [`haggis.logs.add_logging_level`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.logs.add_logging_level) which may be below 10 (DEBUG). I'm coming to the conclusion that the intent is for zero (NOTSET) to be NaN when it comes for logging levels though, and I'm just overthinking the whole thing.

Comment: @9769953. This question, and a few others I recently asked came about because I was finally writing unit tests for the function I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make a non-root logger log all messages of any severity without delegating to a parent at any point?

Here is an answer to your question:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('name') # non-root logger
logger.propagate = False # never delegate to a parent
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) # debug is the lowest existing log level, so this will log everything
```

this also traps any logs from loggers that are below this one in the hierarchy ... so `name.child` would also not reach root.

Edit: if you are using custom log levels than set the level to whatever is the lowest, or use some constant that will always be lower: `logger.setLevel(-99999999)`
I highly recommend not using custom log levels though, there are only few cases where that is really the preferred solution.

Comment: I'm unit testing a function that specifically allows the creation of levels below DEBUG. Will this method work in that case? Does the real magic happen by setting `logger.propagate = False`, or in setting the level?

Comment: If you're curious: https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.logs.add_logging_level and https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.logs.add_trace_level

Comment: @MadPhysicist made an edit concerning custom log levels. The "real magic" does indeed happen mostly with setting propagate to false.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of findings:

1. Logging with level `NOTSET` appears to discard the messages as well: some non-zero severity appears to be necessary for this to work at all.
2. Any numerical value other than strictly zero seems to be valid, including negative numbers.

So any of the following appear to be valid solutions:

- `logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET - 1)`
- `logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET + 1)`
- `logger.setLevel(1)`

Comment: NOTSET means the level is obtained from the first ancestor logger which has a level. You seem to be definitely overthinking this stuff, it's not that complicated but you seem to be doing a few things that aren't recommended practice. Perhaps you should review the documentation again, specifically the `getEffectiveLevel()` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel

Comment: @VinaySajip. I did. I think the problem is that I came in with the idea that all integers would be valid logging levels, but in fact zero has special meaning. Once that idea penetrated my skull, the setup actually became quite clear.

Comment: @VinaySajip. Is there any reason that I couldn't use a floating-point logging level?

Comment: @VinaySajip. FWIW, I think that my question makes sense even before the overthinking: having a non-root logger trap all child messages seems like a useful thing to be able to do.

Comment: Floating point levels - why would you even want to? They're not needed and not especially supported, so you would be on your own if you run into problems. What do you mean by "non-root logger trap all child messages"? Did you read the advanced tutorial about logging flow? https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow

Comment: @VinaySajip. I did. The usecase of a library that adds a NullHandler to its namespace logger until the user sets an explicit configuration is exactly what I'm talking about. You would have to set the level of the namespace logger at some small non-zero value, say DEBUG. Now if your library starts using a custom level of 5 for some really granular debugging, you have to remember to set the level of the namespace logger to avoid having those messages propagate up to the root logger. By setting the level to 1 or -1 or some small other non-zero level, the maintenance issue is avoided

Comment: @VinaySajip. I was just curious about floats. Wasn't planning to use them, but didn't see anything in the code that would cause a problem, since they're hashable and rich-comparable to other numbers. I didn't see anywhere that the levels were used as an index or anything like that.

Comment: @VinaySajip. By non-root logger, I meant something like the top level logger in a library namespace. By trapping all child messages I meant preventing any messages from deeper within the namespace from propagating out to the root logger. Sorry for the poor phrasing. And for asking for so much of your time. I really appreciate the opportunity to pick your brain.